# Not able to copy files in a Azure DevOps pipeline running container

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline running a container. I want to copy a file from my repository to a directory inside that container. I am using following code block for that.

```
stages:
- stage: Rancher_Configuration
  jobs:
  - job: 
    pool: $(agentPool)
    displayName: Setup ansible
    container:
      image: $(container_image)
    steps:
      - script: |
            whoami
            ls -al /usr/local/onesaitplatform-rancher2
            chown vsts_azpcontainer /usr/local/onesaitplatform-rancher2/hosts
            cp $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Step-01/hosts  /usr/local/onesaitplatform-rancher2/hosts
        displayName: copy hosts
            
      - task: CopyFiles@1
        displayName: move host file
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Step-01'
          Contents: 'hosts'
          TargetFolder: '/usr/local/onesaitplatform-rancher2'
          OverWrite: true
```

its failing with given error :

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/onesaitplatform-rancher2/hosts': Permission denied
```

I have tried with both copy task as well Linux copy command but same outcome.